# When I start to compile the form the navabar disappear framework7

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I’ve a strange problem… When I start to compile the form the navbar slowly begins a fading until it disappears altogether. The same behavoiur if I use the tab on the keyboard to move from one input to another. I don’t understand the reason… It appens with the form.. I had the same problem with another form..
I thought that could be a div didn't close. I checked the code but it seems correct... but I don't know another possible cause

this is my html page

```html
<div data-name="users-add" class="page">

  <div class="page-content pg-no-padding">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-80">
        <div class="block">
          <form class="list" id="form-add-user">

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-80">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <h2> Add User</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-content card-content-padding">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center margin padding">Compile...</div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
                        <div class="list no-hairlines-md">
                          <ul>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <div class="item-title item-label">Nome</div>
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="" name="first_name">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title item-label">Surname</div>
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="" name="last_name">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title item-label">Email</div>
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <input type="email" placeholder="" name="email">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title item-label">Password</div>
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <input type="password" placeholder="" name="password">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title item-label">Confirm password</div>
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <input type="password" placeholder="" name="password_confirm">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title item-label">Phone</div>
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <input type="tel" placeholder="" name="phone">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>

                            <li class="item-content item-input">
                              <div class="item-inner">
                                <div class="item-title item-label">Name Company</div>
                                <div class="item-input-wrap">
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="" name="company">
                                  <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--list-->
                      </div>
                      <!--col-->
                    </div>
                    <!--row-->
                    <div class="row justify-content-center margin padding">Role</div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-100 tablet-auto desktop-auto">
                        <div class="list no-hairlines-md">
                          <ul>
                            <li>
                              <label class="item-radio item-content">
               <input type="radio" name="id_user" value="1" checked />
               <i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
               <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title"> Superadmin </div>
               </div>
              </label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <label class="item-radio item-content">
               <input type="radio" name="id_user" value="2" />
               <i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
               <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title"> Profile A </div>
               </div>
              </label>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                              <label class="item-radio item-content">
               <input type="radio" name="id_user" value="3" />
               <i class="icon icon-radio"></i>
               <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title"> Profile B </div>
               </div>
              </label>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--list-->
                      </div>
                      <!--col-->
                    </div>
                    <!--row-->

                    <div class="block margin padding">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                          <a class="button button-fill" onclick="addUser()">Save</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- ./ block - save button -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- ./ block -->
                  </div>
                  <!--card-content-->
                </div>
                <!--.card-->
              </div>
              <!--.col-->
            </div>
            <!--.row-->
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- ./ block -->
      </div>
      <!--.col-->
    </div>
    <!-- .row-->

  </div>
  <!-- ./ page-content -->
```